# how to return the sum of a value in a table with where clause in grails 2.5.0

Tags: sql, grails

Domain class:

```
class Transaction {
   String roundId
   BigDecimal amount
   :
}
```

The SQL we wish to execute the following:

"select sum(t.amount) from transaction t where t.roundId = xxx"

We have been unable to find an example which does not  return Transaction rows.

We assume there are two approaches:

1. Use projections and/or criteria etc?  All the examples we have found only return lists of transaction rows, not the sum.
2. Use raw SQL.  How do we call SQL, and get a handle on the BigDecimal it returns?

I tried this:

```
class bla{
def sessionFactory
def someMethod() {
    def SQLsession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    def results = SQLsession.createSQLQuery("select sum(t.credit) from transaction t where t.round_id = :roundId", [roundId: roundId])
```

But this fails with

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createSQLQuery() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.LinkedHashMap)
```

Also, I have no idea what the return type would be (cant find any documentation). I am guessing it will be a list of something: Arrays? Maps?

==== UPDATE ====

Found one way which works (not very elegant or grails like)

```
    def SQLsession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    final query = "select sum(t.credit) from transaction t where t.round_id = :roundId"
    final sqlQuery = SQLsession.createSQLQuery(query)
    final results = sqlQuery.with {
        setString('roundId', roundId)
        list()  // what is this for?  Is there a better return value?
    }
```

This seems to return an array, not a list as expected, so I can do this:

```
if (results?.size == 1) {
    println results[0] // outputs a big decimal
}
```

Strangely, results.length fails, but results.size works.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Criteria`, you can do

```
Transaction.withCriteria {
    eq 'roundId', yourRoundIdValueHere
    projections {
        sum 'amount'
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting!  What is the returned object?  Is it a list of Transactions, or just the summed amount?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/classic/Session.html

```
 Query  createSQLQuery(String sql, String[] returnAliases, Class[] returnClasses) 
 Query  createSQLQuery(String sql, String returnAlias, Class returnClass)
```

The second argument of `createSQLQuery` is one or more `returnAliases` and not meant for binding the statement to a value.

Instead of passing your values in the 2nd argument, use the setters of your [Query object](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Query.html) i.e. `setString`, `setInteger`, etc.

```
results.setInteger('roundId',roundId);
```